# Webform page avoiding runat server

Tags: .net, webforms

I have a bit of a problem with a page that needs some re-writing.

Basically, the page on `$(document).ready` calls via ajax a web service and gets a json object back and then uses that object and a template to generate the page. This works perfectly... until you turn js off and then you just see a blank page.

Anyways, I have been told to make it work for non-js people... and indexable re Google

Now ordinarily I would just make something like `<asp:label id="name" runat="server">` and then in code behind fill it. But due to all the other JS that is attached to the page to the different divs and labels etc I am trying to avoid this. E.g. Masonry js is attached amongst others.

Obviously if I change the stuff to runat server then the ids change.

So the question, can I just have in the aspx page simple html and e.g. `<%= presult.Name %>` and in the code behind something like `AWebService ws = new AWebService(); var result = ws.Getdata....` and then made the 'result' public with `public MyClass presult {get;set;}`

**Question**: Is there any performance problem in doing this over the alternative of making labels `runat=server`? Is there any other glaring problem in doing this (I have never used .net in this way on the aspx page with <%%> tags. Have read about it, but never used it....  It would seem a more 'light weight' alternative given it avoids all the extra stuff put in if you use a server side control label...

Note: I was looking at MVC today amongst my readings. Am I correct in saying that if I don't have `runat=server` but the other way above that it is kind of like MVC using the aspx view engine ?
Also, I have seen the posts re making ajax calls `#!` but we are trying to avoid using those hash tags if possible.

Thanks in advance

Cheers,
Robin

**EDIT**

As a note, to avoid jumbled client side ids on controls, .net 4.0 has the `ClientIDMode` which you can set to static....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with the approach you are trying to take.
But i would rather put the result inside a couple of noscript tags to ensure they only get displayed when js is turned off.

```
<noscript>
    <%= presult.Name %>
</noscript>
```

Comment: Thanks for that tip, good idea actually! Do you know if there is a perf hit doing it this way? I image not....

Comment: @RobinRieger besides the service call i don't think there is any that would matter.